# Display Template for IEnumerable<interface>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, ienumerable, mvc-editor-templates

I'm trying to use a Display Template for an IEnumerable collection of an interface, and for some reason I cannot get the Display Template to display for the interface.

Here's some brief code to show you what I mean.

I have `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/IUserMessage.vbhtml` with some trivial view code.

I also have `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/UserMessages.vbhtml`:

```
@Imports WebUI.UserMessages
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of IUserMessage)
<div id="UserMessages">
    '@Html.DisplayForModel("IUserMessage") 'This doesn't work either
     @Html.DisplayForModel()
</div>
```

And in `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml` I have

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.UserMessages) 'm.UserMessages is List(Of IUserMessage) with a UIHint of "UserMessages"
```

I step through the code, and it gets into the `UserMessages` display template just fine. However, the code never reaches the `IUserMessage` display template.